# pod install causes error "unknown file type" when creating Acknowledgements.plist

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I'm using CocoaPods for my app.

One of the modules is written in Swift, so my Podfile is as below.

```
platform :ios, "8.0"
use_frameworks!

target "ossTest" do
    pod 'Charts', "~> 2.0"
    pod "Color-Picker-for-iOS", "~> 2.0"
end

post_install do | installer |
require 'fileutils'

FileUtils.cp_r('Pods/Target Support Files/Pods/Pods-Acknowledgements.plist', 'ossTest/Settings.bundle/Acknowledgements.plist', :remove_destination => true)
# error
#FileUtils.cp_r('Pods/Pods-acknowledgements.plist', 'ossTest/Settings.bundle/Acknowledgements.plist', :remove_destination => true)

end
```

When I run `pod install`, an error message appears:

```
[!] An error occurred while processing the post-install hook of the Podfile.

unknown file type: Pods/Target Support Files/Pods/Pods-Acknowledgements.plist
```

Of course, I've prepared Setting.bundle and inside the bundle, I've created an empty Acknowledgement.plist, and modified root.plist to the suggested setting.

My CocoaPods' version is 0.39.0.

How can I solve the error?

Comment: I am also having the same problem. Did you figure out what is happening?

Comment: I couldn't solve it yet. And I decided wasting time for this.
Now I'm using VTAcknowledgementsViewController at https://github.com/vtourraine/VTAcknowledgementsViewController.

This works fine for me.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In my case, I was just running `pod install` in the wrong directory. Obviously, because file paths in your Podfile are relative, it means you should run the script from your project's root directory.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: I had the exact same issue. Thanks you saved me a lot of time.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out the issue is not with CocoaPods. Instead it can't find a file at the provided location... Go in finder and insure there is a file at "Pods/Target Support Files/Pods/Pods-Acknowledgements.plist"

Comment: For me, when I upgraded CocoaPods and had to specify a target name, all these support files went into Pods-target/Pods-target-Acknowledgements.plist ... etc as well. After updating these paths, all is good.